# Loop through html tables data and submit back to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have spent the last couple of hours battling to write some javascript and jquery.

Basically I am trying to loop through a table checking if an attribute exists within a TD if it does add its info into an array and post it back to the server

My code (I am sure it could be better)

```
      $("#save-changes").click(function () {
        var param = [];
        var table = $("#products-grid > .t-grid-content > table tbody tr").each(function (i) {
            //find checkboxes using class
            var td = ($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").find(".cb"));
            var attr = $(td).attr('data-item');

            if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                console.log(td);
                param.push({ "itemId": attr, "productId": td.val() });
            }
        });
        console.log(param);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ApplyProduct")',
            data:  param,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (e) {
```

I am now stuck on trying to pass the array back to the server. What do I need to do to send the data back to the server as a parameter the server can understand?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add two parameters

```
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify(param)
```

to your .ajax call.

Crate an object server side which has two int properties int called itemId and productId and then create a JsonResult route that takes an array of your object that you post too (this would be ApplyProduct in your case).

Comment: Unless you're using a stringify plugin to support IE, this isn't cross browser compatiable. It is a good approach but requires a plugin for IE.

Comment: as Spalsh-x says depending on browser you may need a js lib for json.stringify to work, you test if the function exists and if it doesnt you include the extra lib. It is natively supported in newer IE's.

Comment: Oh, you'll probably have to make sure the array of this object is called param in the route method signature

Answer (score 0):

you cannot send arrays to a server , they have to be strings.

you could join the array together like this

```
param.join(";");
```

that would create a string with each value seperated by a ;

also you need to specify the data option as a key-value json

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ApplyProduct")',
    data:  {
        param : param
    },
    type: 'POST',
```

then on the serverside you can split the string back into an array

```
$param = explode(";",$_POST['param']);
```

Comment: damn kmcc's answer is better :)